# Bind Button.Command to another element by name

Tags: wpf, binding, command, action

I have `Button`, named `left_button` and `ScrollViewer`, named `scrollv`. How can I bind `Button.Command` to `ScrollViewer.LineLeftCommand` without code-behind?

Comment: Do you want to bind both `Button.Command` and `ScrollViewer.LineLeftCommand` to the same `ICommand`?

Comment: ScrollViewer have some command and I want call it from button click without code-behind. 
Maybe I'm not doing it right, I'm not worked with WPF seriously more than two years.

Comment: I was looking for the `ScrollViewer.LineLeftCommand` but didn't find it. Do you mean `ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand`? Have you looking for: `<Button Command="ScrollViewer.LineLeftCommand" ... />`

Comment: O, thanks. Used with CommandTarget={Binding ElementName=name}, all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hamlet Hakobyan.
Bound to ScrollBar:

```
<Button Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_HorizontalScrollBar}"/>
```